# No such module 'FacebookLogin'

Tags: swift3, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working on an app with Firebase and Facebook SDKs, but I have a problem installing Facebook SDK for some reason. Firebase works just fine and I've followed the official facebook [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started) for Swift. Here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp_iOS' do

use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyApp_iOS
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

I'm getting the 'no such module "FacebookLogin"' error when I try importing FacebookLogin. I've tried installing FBSDKCoreKit and changing platform 9.0 to 10.0 but I got same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I am experiencing similar issues.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. After installing pods you need to open your-project-name.xcworkspace file, which is your project file you need to use to get everything working. I was following firebase instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup , though it worked for me after installing facebook login pod as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a directory for your project
2. Create a new Xcode project in the directory from step 1
3. In the directory you created run *pod init*
4. This will create a Podfile
5. In the Podfile add the pods you need
6. Run *pod install* this will download the needed pod files and create an .xcworkspace file with a name like MyApp_iOS.xcworkspace.
7. Close the existing xccodeproj file and open the xcworkspace file
8. Make all you changes in the xcworkspace file.  Now FacebookLogin is available.

Special thanks to Thiago for his help with this issue.

Comment: it solved my problem. and i think it's very stupid - i mean how i can not run my initial xcode project. thanks a lot.